# Drupal 7 Webform redirect

Tags: redirect, drupal-7, drupal-webform

We have a Drupal 7 webform that redirects to a url upon successful submission.

What we need to do is redirect the user if they land on the same webform again and have already submitted.

Do we need a module for this, or do it programmatically?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution that we ended up going with.

1. I saved the webform and made it available as a block
2. I created a page to hold the webform
3. I configured the block to appear above the page content
4. In the page content I put in some javascript to detect if the form element was present - if not forward to the correct url

So the webform redirects correctly upon submission(set in the webform settings), and it then redirects if the user lands back on that page and has completed the webform.

Answer (score 1):

I looked through the webform module and didn't find any setting that will redirect the user if the user has already submitted a form, so I think you need to do it programmatically.

*Note: It might be possible without a custom module by using the rules module. I haven't tried this.*

To do it programmatically you could do something like below. It implements the `hook_node_view()` and checks if the user has already submitted anything by using the webform api function `webform_get_submission_count()`. (*edit: the custom module in this example is called example_webform*)

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_node_view().
 */
function example_webform_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  global $user;
  module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.submissions');
  $submission_count = webform_get_submission_count($node->nid, $user->uid);
  if (!empty($submission_count) && $submission_count > 0) {
    $redirect = $node->webform['redirect_url'];
    drupal_goto($redirect);
  }
}
```

As it is now it will reuse the page that is used when the form is submitted, so if you choose to do this remember to make the success page reflect this. (E.g. it would be strange for the success page to say "your post has been saved" if the user lands on it for the second time.) Or you could replace the `$redirect` with another page than the one from the webform setting.

Also note that the webform will still add the message "You have already submitted this form. View your previous submissions." if this is enabled.

Comment: Thanks Troels. We will test this next week if we don't find a module solution.